# I can't get my added element to activate a function

Tags: onclick, colorbox, insertafter

I am trying to add a link to the [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) interface as it is created. It will eventually link to the currently displayed image file but for now I just want to get the console.log to work. It adds the link correctly (#print-one) but I can't get a function to run when the link is clicked. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
    // Show close button with a delay.
    $('#cboxClose').css('opacity', 1);
    // Add Print Button
    if ($('#print-one').length ) {
        // Do Nothing
    }else {
        $('#cboxNext').after('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="print-one">Print</a>');
    }
});

$('#print-one').click(function() {
    console.log('Works');
});
```

This is all wrapped inside the $(document).ready function. I just can't get the console log to work when the link is clicked. I have been beating my head against a wall trying to figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens if you move the `$('#print....).click` in the `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the event.

`$(document).on('click', '#print-one', function(){});`

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had tried something similar to this that didn't work, but I had #print-one where you have document. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the link is added just after cbox is initialized, which may not be ready when the compiler gets to the click binding function a few lines below.

Try this:

```
...
// Add Print Button
if ($('#print-one').length ) {
    // Do Nothing
}else {
    $('<a href="#">Print</a>').insertAfter('#cboxNext').click(function() {
        console.log('Works');
    });
}
```